# How can I position two divs with overlapping corners like links in a chain?

Tags: html, css

I don't know what code to write to ensure the borders of two divs are anchored to each other like a chain.

I don't have any code because I have not thought of reasonable solution to it.

[image: demonstrative image of two divs with borders interlinked like links on a chian]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used 3d transform.

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid;
}

.a {
  border-color: tomato;
}

.b {
  border-color: royalblue;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  transform: rotateX(-0.1deg); /* here! */
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="a box"></div>
  <div class="b box"></div>
</div>
```